# How to sort lines by float number

Tags: sort, numeric-data

I've such a file:

```
name: xxx --- time: 5.4 seconds
name: yyy --- time: 3.2 seconds
name: zzz --- time: 6.4 seconds
...
```

Now I want to sort this file by these float numbers to generate a new file as below:

```
name: yyy --- time: 3.2 seconds
name: xxx --- time: 5.4 seconds
name: zzz --- time: 6.4 seconds
...
```

I've tried the command `awk '{print $5}' myfile | sort -g` but this will show me ONLY the float numbers.

Comment: is the problem including values with multiple leading digits and with maybe negative values?
there further might be the chance to have exponential notation in large, small and non-needed cases.
left alone the fact that a float can be even a "NaN" and its relatives.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If using GNU `sort` or compatible, you can use its `-g` switch to do a general numeric sort:

```
$ sort -g -k5,5 file
name: yyy --- time: 3.2 seconds
name: xxx --- time: 5.4 seconds
name: zzz --- time: 6.4 seconds
```

The `-k5,5` tells sort to perform the sort on just the 5th column.

#### Usage

Keep in mind the details from the `info sort` page:

> ```
> '-g'
> '--general-numeric-sort'
> '--sort=general-numeric'
>      Sort numerically, converting a prefix of each line to a long
>      double-precision floating point number.  *Note Floating point::.
>      Do not report overflow, underflow, or conversion errors.  Use the
>      following collating sequence:
>
>         * Lines that do not start with numbers (all considered to be
>           equal).
>         * NaNs ("Not a Number" values, in IEEE floating point
>           arithmetic) in a consistent but machine-dependent order.
>         * Minus infinity.
>         * Finite numbers in ascending numeric order (with -0 and +0
>           equal).
>         * Plus infinity.
>
>      Use this option only if there is no alternative; it is much slower
>      than '--numeric-sort' ('-n') and it can lose information when
>      converting to floating point.
> ```

Comment: Note that for numbers like `3.2`, standard `sort -n` would be enough (provided the locale's radix character is that `.`). You'd need the `-g` GNU extension for numbers like 1e20, 0x20, inf...

Comment: Had to use `LC_ALL=C sort -g ...` to get my sort to work.

Comment: @AxelBregnsbo same here, my locale uses a comma as decimal separator, so I had to use `LC_NUMERIC=C sort` (ALL also works, of course). Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Apparently this option is incompatible with `-u` (to remove duplicate lines): with `-g`, when determining whether two lines are “identical”, only the floating-point number is taken into account!